# SQLite does not update the date value

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am trying to update the date value in the database which is hold as a text, however I stucked here, it takes the user correctly, but does not update the current date;

```
    public int getID(String userName) {
        String colums[] = {userName};
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE userName=?";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql,colums);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
            if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
            int id = cursor.getInt(0);
            db.close();
            cursor.close();
            return id;
        }
        db.close();
        cursor.close();
        return 0;
    }
```

The part that I try to update the date, the app is closed suddenly;

```
    public void update(User user, String currentDate){

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        int ID =  getID(user.getUserName());
        String strSQL = "UPDATE user SET date = " + currentDate + " WHERE id =?" + ID ;
        db.execSQL(strSQL);
        db.close();
    }
```

Comment: Do you need to enclose ```date = ' " + currentDate + " ' ```with single quotes?

Comment: Your statement is a bit weird, use it with parameters like you did in your select query.  You can't just concat the date with the rest of the query. And see how the last part will look after concatenation - you're appending the ID to the question mark? Use params - these will not only protect you from sql injection, but also make your update work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String strSQL = "UPDATE user SET date = " + currentDate + " WHERE id =?" + ID ;
```

Seems like **SYNTAX** (May be Quotes) issue costs you. You can try with

```
 public void update(User user, String currentDate){

    int user_id =  getID(user.getUserName());
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues data=new ContentValues();
    data.put("date",currentDate);
    db.update("user", data, "id=" + String.valueOf(user_id), null);
    db.close();
 }
```